# Why not working this library?

Tags: jquery, html, css, simplemodal

I have this script:

[link](https://jsfiddle.net/0t62sjqp/3/)

**HTML:**

```
<p class="element_to_pop_up">Test</p>
```

**JS:**

```
$('element_to_pop_up').bPopup();
```

I used this [library](http://dinbror.dk/bpopup/)

Why not work to implement?
You know any other library that works?

Can I please ajutato me solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need a (dot) infront of class name and you forget to add external library bpopup in your jsfiddle.

Comment: I put dot in front and library is add,you can check again please?I update my jsdfiddle

Comment: You need to add this script after jquery script: https://raw.github.com/dinbror/bpopup/master/jquery.bpopup.min.js

Comment: added dot infront of class name and working fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xy0L0jop/)